# Change image overlay on demand

Tags: ffmpeg

I need your help. I stream to Twitch with this Command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i image.jpg -filter_complex 'overlay=x=10:x=10' -s \
  1920x1200 -framerate 15  -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -threads 0 -f flv 'rtmp://'
```

How is it possible to change the `image.jpg` picture to another picture on a variable time? I will don't restart the FFMPEG Command.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-f image2 -loop 1` input options for the image input, then atomically replace `image.jpg` when desired such as by using `mv`.

Basic example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f image2 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex overlay output.mp4
```

Streaming example:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -f image2 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "overlay,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -g 50 -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 8000k -f flv 'rtmp://'
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "variable time" part of your question use a cron job to run scripts that update the overlay image at a specified time i.e. every 5 mins. For example you can create a folder of various overlays and select one randomly every 5 minutes and copy it to image.jpg. FFMPEG will then render the new image to your stream.

It is important to use `-f image 2 -loop 1 -thread_queue_size 512 -i image.jpg` especially when rendering other image formats.