# Keep ffmpeg converting images to video when new images are incoming

Tags: java, c++, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Is there a way to keep ffmpeg convert images incoming to HLS, and stop whenever I want?

I'm using ffmpeg to convert images to m3u8/ts for streaming. A camera device will send images 24/7, and ffmpeg will convert those when users requested until they stop watching.

For now, I get images from a camera device by Java network, then move those images to ffmpeg input directory and convert those with C++. It's a loop that does this job, so new ffmpeg is executed every time images are moved.

The problem is there are too many ts files leftover, and they're taking a lot of spaces on server. So I tried to delete those with delete_segments option, but since ffmpeg is executed every time, it couldn't delete segments made from ffmpeg right before it.

Here are some ways I consider:

1. To remove files with another function, without ffmpeg.
2. Maybe transfer images directly to ffmpeg input, and somehow make ffmpeg keep convert those images to ts. (And I couldn't think of somehow)
3. Or maybe change the whole structure.

It would be much easier with the option 1, but it would be great if I can do this with ffmpeg's own functions.

Comment: ffmpeg should update the image automatically, assuming `-i image.jpg` and every time it needs an update another image is atomically renamed `image.jpg` replacing the old one. Can't really suggest anything else without seeing your command. See [Change image overlay on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465041/change-image-overlay-on-demand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an input file list, which can be a special file (e.g. a FIFO pipe).

Then your command may look like:

```sh
mkfifo mylist.pipe
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.pipe output.mkv
```

And you can add every image to mylist.pipe, as follows:

```
echo "file '/path/to/image.png'"  >mylist.pipe
echo "file '/path/to/image2.png'" >mylist.pipe
```

If the paths are relative, you don't need the `-safe 0` part.

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#Automaticallyappendingtothelistfile