# how to set opacity/transparency of overlay using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am making an app where I need to overlay two video files one above the other using `ffmpeg`. I tried various commands but all it does is merging a video.

Comment: If you wish to stack videos, seee https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/5726027

Comment: it is kind of merging video.i don't wont that . is it possible to overlay one video on another video.

Comment: For regular overlay, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405214/5726027

Comment: i need to overlay  two video file (Like 2  video blending ) with opacity  or transparency @Gyan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic method is

```
ffmpeg -i in1 -i in2 -filter_complex
       "[1]format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[in2];[0][in2]overlay"
       out
```

where `0.5` sets 50% transparency for the 2nd input. The format filter is needed to make sure that the 2nd video has an alpha channel.

To resize in2 to match in1, use

```
ffmpeg -i in1 -i in2 -filter_complex
       "[1]format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[in2];
        [in2][0]scale2ref[in2][in1];[in1][in2]overlay"
       out
```

Comment: thanks  @Gyan that's  working! The video is overlay-ed, but the overlay-ed video width and height is too small. So how can  i set  width  and height  of both videos equal ?

Comment: have can you  help  me?  how can it work  fast? @Gyan

Comment: You can speed it up slightly by doing a manual scale.  You may be able to speed up encoding by adding `-preset veryfast` but that depends on which encoder you're using.

Comment: Instead of `colorchannelmixer` you could use a lighter filter like [lut](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lut_002c-lutrgb_002c-lutyuv) and set the alpha channel to 255*{alpha percentage} like so: `lut=a=255*0.5`

Comment: Changing the format to YUV all the time can be very taxing, especially if the input format is RGB, so you could let ffmpeg choose the best format with alpha to use out of a provided list, like so `format=yuva420p|yuva444p|yuva422p|rgba|abgr|bgra|gbrap|ya8`; here we ask ffmpeg to choose best format between all variants of yuv, rgb and/or grayscale. To see all supported pixel formats, use `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`