# Overlaying multiple videos with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay multiple videos into one video with ffmpeg. [There is already a question with only one overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890738/overlaying-video-with-ffmpeg), but I want to add multiple videos at the same time (to avoid multiple encodings).

I try to use following line:

```
ffmpeg -i background.m2v -vf "movie=a.m2v [a]; movie=b.m2v [b]; [in][a] overlay=0:366, [b] overlay=592:41" combined.m2v
```

The error is now, that the overlay area (0,366) – (720,942) is not within the main area (0,0) – (720, 210). But if I use only one overlay file alone it works.

The sizes of the videos:

- background: 720x576
- a.m2v: 72x48
- b.m2v: 720x210

In the result I want the a.m2v video in the top left corner (the logo) and the b.m2v as a lower third.

Comment: See my detailed answer at [Superimposing two videos onto a static image?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13405214/1109017). Although "static image" is mentioned the process is basically the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested this with `mp4`, but `m2v` should work as well

```sh
set 'overlay, overlay = 0:366'
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4 -filter_complex "$1" combined.mp4
```

[§ overlay](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1)

Comment: The first overlay is incomplete. With “overlay=592:41,overlay=0:366” it works. Also I'm interested in the reason why my solution didn't work out.

Comment: @xZise the `overlay=592:41` is strange, top left should require no argument.

Answer (score 0):

I also find a answer/workaround before svnpenn:

```
ffmpeg -i background.m2v -vf "movie=a.m2v [a]; movie=b.m2v [b]; [in][a] overlay=0:366 [c]; [c][b] overlay=592:41" combined.m2v
```