# ffmpeg overlay video with semi transparent video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to overlay background video with another semi transparent video using ffmpeg.

Thanks to [Overlaying multiple videos with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676517/overlaying-multiple-videos-with-ffmpeg) I managed to put video overlay over background video.

The problem is that I don't know how to make overlay video semitransparent.

So far I am using following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_105470127_044810.mp4 -vf "movie=VID_21550603_142437.mp4 [a]; [in][a] overlay=10:10 [c]" combined.mp4

ffmpeg -i VID_105470127_044810.mp4  -i VID_21550603_142437.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay, overlay=10:10" combined.mp4
```

I tried to play with fade effect but this is not what I want. Please point me out where to look and what can I try to achieve this.

**UPDATE #1**

It looks like blend filter is exactly what I need but another issue came out:

```
ffmpeg -i video1280x720.mp4 -vf "movie=video640x640.mp4 [a]; [in][a] overlay=10:10 [c]" combined.mp4

[Parsed_blend_3 @ 0x7f8041500da0] First input link top parameters (size 1280x720, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding second input link bottom parameters (640x640, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_blend_3 @ 0x7f8041500da0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_blend_3
```

So probably if I can resolve issue with different resolutions I am done with my task.
Please advice what is the direction to go.

**UPDATE#2**

To solve different resolution problem I decided to crop video and then proceed with blending filter

```
ffmpeg -i VID_1920x1080.mp4 -filter:v "crop=640:640:0:0" -c:a copy VID_1920x1080_cropped.mp4

ffmpeg -i VID_1920x1080_cropped.mp4 -i VID_21550603_142437.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1:0] setdar=dar=1,format=rgba [a]; [0:0]setdar=dar=1,format=rgba [b]; [b][a]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.8" blended.mp4
```

Comment: there appears to be opacity options for the blend filter, FWIW

Comment: yes, I already discovered parameter that controls opacity, but really my current problem is to blend two videos of different resolution

Comment: possibly overlay the one that's too small first [?]

Answer (score 2):

As solution I managed to crop file:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_1920x1080.mp4 -filter:v "crop=640:640:0:0" -c:a copy VID_1920x1080_cropped.mp4
```

...and then blend with another video:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_1920x1080_cropped.mp4 -i VID_21550603_142437.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[1:0]setdar=dar=1,format=rgba[a]; \
 [0:0]setdar=dar=1,format=rgba[b]; \
 [b][a]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.8" \
blended.mp4
```

Comment: The standalone crop command is unnecessary when you can just do it all in one command: `[0:v]crop,setdar,format[b];[1:v]setdar,format[a];[a][b]blend`

Comment: overlay video is not play smooth :(

Answer (score -2):

Below library supports support combine two videos by overlay one on other while they are playing without ffmpeg.

https://github.com/LanSoSdk/LanSoEditor_advance

I have checked this library, this library is developed base on GPUImage(opengl es).

Current library is not free version.