# how to schedule overlap between two video files?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 2 mp4 videos. One is the main movie and the second is an ending file. A part of the ending file is partly transparent and i want to create a new file with overlap between the files.

For example:
The length of the main.mp4 file is 10:00 minutes. The length of the ending.mp4 file is 2:00 minutes, the first minute is partly transparent.

I want to create a new file As follows:
1-9 minutes of main.mp4
9-10 minute ending.mp4 file overlay the main.mp4 file, I want to overlap them both.
10-11 minute the rest of ending.mp4.

Is there a way to do it in ffmpeg or in another video framework? I tried to search but did not find a way to schedule the overlap

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676517/overlaying-multiple-videos-with-ffmpeg

Comment: thank you, but not exactly. I want the ending file to start  in the middle of the main file, and to continue after the main finish. how can I schedule the ending file and to determine it when to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

offset second video, overlay from 540 sec using enable:

`ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -itsoffset 540 -i ending.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay='enable=gt(t,540)'[v]" -map [v] output.mp4`