# ffmpeg concat list of videos keeping aspect ratio 16:9 for 1080p output

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I have looked through the internet for 1 hr now and there are a lot of answers but none works :((

So i have a folder with x amount of videos (.mp4) which have different aspect ratios (4:3, 16:9, 1:3) and so on. I want them all to be concat within a 1080p canvas. I tried all commands i could find but none worked.

my text file creation using CMD: for %i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%i') > mylist.txt

content of text file:

```
file 'dave.mp4'
file 'harry.mp4'
file 'lisa.mp4'
file 'john.mp4'
file 'bill.mp4'
file 'hans.mp4'
```

Now I found many ffmpeg commands, the only one that worked was this but this automaticatlly takes the first videos resolution and merges all vids resulting in a black screen for most of the videos:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

I read so many complicated commands that I feel dizzy now, isn't here a way to simply just add a parameter of the canvas size (my desired resolution would be 1920x1080 which is 16:9 and automatically fit all videos proportionally within that frame.

can someone PLEASE help me?

Sinceraly
Gram

Comment: The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366845/how-to-concatenate-videos-in-ffmpeg-with-different-attributes) looks most relevant (use concat filter instead of the concat demuxer).

Comment: yeah but the problem is thta he is listing 3 videos manually i want to work with my generated list because i dunno how many videos i get :/ And my coding is so bad that i can't manage to edit it properly

Comment: You may use a Python script (or other) for generating the command from a list of files. If you don't know any programming you are in the wrong place.

Comment: also: the plattform doesn't allow me to ask in another thread because I need 50 reputation to add a comment :/

Comment: Do i have to learn every language for anything? isn't ffmpeg able to do it? why python?

Comment: You are right with the command list though rotem, i am building it right now. cheers, no python needed!

Comment: I commented "Python script (**or other**)". I though I had some Python example ready, but I can't find it.

Comment: I found my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170397/4926757), but I am not sure if it's going to help.

Comment: well i used windows batch commands to create a list of commands ina batch file and those work but now i have another problem. And I can't find any answers to that, all videos are now in a 1080p window but when combining the vertical videos get stretched

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/547296/resizing-videos-with-ffmpeg-avconv-to-fit-into-static-sized-player)?

Comment: I even found that thread :D i tried so many solutions that i feel dizzy, I think the given scripts there gave me errors and when fixing them the frame rate was broken. this is driving em nuts, u fix one thing but then it generates another problem. I guess i will create a new question and list all command and explain the problem, I'm sure i am missing something simple...